# How to display BLOB content in php

Tags: php, mysql

Iv try to display BLOB-1B content or image in PHP, I have an app in Android that take an image then upload to my host mysql I have no problem with upload now its time to display in PHP, here is my code.

```
    //config.php
    public function _owners_img($stall_id){
    $request ="SELECT `img` FROM `img_stall` WHERE `stall_id` = '$stall_id' LIMIT 1";
        $result_query = $this->con->query($request);
       while($data = $result_query->fetch_assoc()){
           $result_data = $data['img'];
       }
       if (!empty($result_data)) {
            return $result_data;
       }else {
          return false; }
     }


   //owner_img.php
   include_once 'config.php';
   $db = new database($con);
   $db->dbconnect();
   $owner = 3;
   echo "<dt><strong>Stall Image:</strong></dt><dd>" . 
       '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. 
        base64_encode($db->_owners_img($owner)).
       '" width="290" height="290">' . "</dd>";
```

but the problem is Am only getting small image icon or image not found. how do I fix this?

Comment: Iv tried using header("content-type: image/jpg"); but still the same

Comment: What's the content of `$db->_owners_img($owner)`? Have you verified that the query is working and returning the expected image data? Are you encoding the image during upload?

Comment: Yes actually I already solve it the problem is just in my android.